# Vim search and replace reference on function call

Tags: regex, vim, reference, replace

How can I replace:
for example PL SQL function call,

```
htp.formRadio('name', 'value', 'checked');
```

to be

```
<input type="radio" name="name" value="value" checked>
```

using vim search and replace regex?

Thank You

Comment: sometimes rather than much around with regex, you can write some macros - e.g. :map q 14xi<input name=^vESC you'll need to figure the rest out yourself, but if it is a one off, I can probably do it quicker this way than with regex...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:s/htp.form\([A-Z][a-z]*\)('\([^']*\)', '\([^']*\)', '\([^']*\)');/<input type="\L\1\E" name="\2" value="\3" \4>/
```

Subject to not having made any typos.  The pattern `'\([^']*\)'` is repeated and captures what's inside the quotes in the call.

Comment: thank you so much! it's working fine. how can I get it work for if the parameter is like ('name'||variable||'name', variable||'value', 'checked');

Comment: You can't because the XML will be screwball.  Or use `[^,]*` in place of `[^']*`, but you have to worry about the single quotes vs double quotes.